# Azure Function to copy blobs from one container to another with different name of blob

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-function-app

So I have two questions here which I am trying to achieve using C# in Azure Functions:

I am suppose to copy blobs from one container to another in same storage account whenever a new blob or directory arrives in the source container. the new blob in destination should have a different name.

I started with my code in Visual Studio using Azure function SDK and I have come up till here:

```
namespace CopyBlobs
{
    public static class CopyBlob
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("SourceContainerName/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]CloudBlockBlob myBlob, IDictionary<string, string> metadata, string name, ILogger log)
         
        
        
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n ContentMD5: {myBlob.Properties.ContentMD5} \n Size: {myBlob.Properties.Length}");
            log.LogInformation($"metadata count {metadata.Count}");
            {
                var destinationContainer = myBlob.Container.ServiceClient.GetContainerReference(metadata["Destination"]);
                destinationContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();                
                CloudBlockBlob outputBlob = destinationContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(name);           
                outputBlob.StartCopyAsync(myBlob);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Q1) I get the error on line  *var destinationContainer = myBl...* as **Destination** key is not defined. I would like to know where and what to define in the Destination key and if anyone can show me an example (I believe it should be my destination container name in localsetting.json file but I am struggling to define it correctly).

Q2) The destination blob which is copied should have a different name, it will be something like the original name manipulated to base64. How can I achieve that?

I am new to do this Azure function thing so i am going slow but hoping to get some quick help here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Q1) I get the error on line var destinationContainer = myBl... as
> Destination key is not defined. I would like to know where and what to
> define in the Destination key and if anyone can show me an example (I
> believe it should be my destination container name in
> localsetting.json file but I am struggling to define it correctly).

You only need the name of the container to lock the container you need. I don't think it needs to involve the concept you mentioned.

This is API reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.database.getcontainer?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Database_GetContainer_System_String_

> Q2) The destination blob which is copied should have a different name,
> it will be something like the original name manipulated to base64. How
> can I achieve that?

You can check this blog:(there have details steps.)

http://gauravmantri.com/2012/11/28/storage-client-library-2-0-migrating-blob-storage-code/

You can set the blob name when create the CloudBlockBlob object of the sink blob. Just need to notice the menthod is changed to 'StartCopyAsync'

`public virtual Task<string> StartCopyAsync(CloudBlockBlob source);`

This is the API reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.startcopyasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy